# Double flag icon appearing when flagging a comment

Tags: bug, comment-flags

I just flagged a comment as "not constructive". Instead of receiving one red flag icon (meaning that you've flagged it), I received two:

[image]

It looks a bug to me. I haven't seen it before. I normally just get one of those icons.

I'm using Google Chrome 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

To if I can reproduce it, I'm not sure. I haven't flagged a comment since that comment flag. But I had flagged a comment just before that flag, and in that, only one icon appeared. I'll inform you when I flag another one.

The comment I flagged was instantly deleted.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with the latest Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Chrome (sorry @Tunaki for flagging your comment).

Comment: Can’t reproduce on Safari 9.0.2.

Comment: Can’t reproduce with Chrome 49.0.2623.112 on OS X (10.10.5). (Sorry @JF for test flag)

Comment: I just flagged 2 comments in a row and only saw one flag each time.

Comment: @user3071284 Thanks. That clears that the second flag in a row is not dependent on the first flag. This was unlikely, but always there is a chance.

Comment: I need to upvote @tuna comment, Firefox 45.0.2 esr.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Debian testing Chromium 49.0.2623.108-1